# Strip duplicate results from custom field wordpress loop of child pages

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, strip

I am looping through all child pages of the current page. I am returning the results of the custom field 'bedrooms'. This is resulting in a list of numbers (numbers of bedrooms) like so - 131413. This is what I expect.

However I want to remove the duplicates so in the example above it will be returned as 134.

I've looked into arrays but and not the best when it comes to php so can anyone help please?

Here's my current code for the child loop and return of acf field.

```
           <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'property',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
                'orderby'       => 'plot_number',
                'order'         => 'ASC'
             );     
            $parent = new WP_Query( $args );    
            if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>

                 <?php the_field('bedrooms'); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: I don't use Wordpress, but you probably want to use a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` as part of your query. Try looking up "Wordpress DISTINCT query". SQL is almost always faster than PHP, so if you can group / distinct in the SQL, that's where you want it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggest would be to put the numbers into an array (an idea you alluded to in your question).

I use `implode()` to join the elements of the array using an empty string (no spaces) as the glue. I'm also using the `array_unique()` function to return a new array without duplicates.

Also note the use of `get_field()` which will return the field value instead of `the_field()` which will output it.

Example:

```
<?php
$bedrooms = array();

while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post();

    // Add 'bedrooms' field value to the array.
    $bedrooms[] = get_field( 'bedrooms' );

endwhile;

// Output as string with no spaces and duplicates removed.
echo implode( '', array_unique( $bedrooms ) ); ?>
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you. I had tried something similar but could not get it to work. One more question if I may, how would I echo the results in number order? Is that possible?

Comment: Pleased I could help. To order you could use the `sort()` function. Change `array_unique( $bedrooms )` to `sort( array_unique( $bedrooms ) )`.

Comment: That breaks the echo? I've used echo implode( '', sort( array_unique( $bedrooms ) ) ); ?> but now have no results?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Sort returns a boolean. Use this instead. 

`sort( $bedrooms );`
`echo implode( '', array_unique( $bedrooms ) );`

Comment: Boom! Please don't apologise, you've been a great help and I have a much better understanding now. Thank you!